# Как передать вариант ответа из <select> на другую php страницу?

Tags: php

У меня на двух php страницах есть:

```
<select>
  <option>1<option>
  <option>2<option>
  <option>3<option>
</select>
```

Как сделать, чтобы на первой странице после выбора варианта например "2", и отправки формы кнопкой, на второй странице в точно таком же:

```
<select>
  <option>1<option>
  <option>2<option>
  <option>3<option>
</select>
```

был выбран вариант "2"?

Answer (score 0):

Нужно почитать, что такое формы и как они отправляются.

1. Нужна форма
2. Нужно имя селекта
3. Нужно value для селекта
4. Нужен метод формы (post или get)
5. На второй странице сравнивать это значение с value и проставлять selected аттрибут

Answer (score 0):

На первой странице дай атрибут `name` твоему `select`, а на второй при помощи `if` добавляй атрибут `selected`

Пример:

Первая страница:

```
<select name="test">
    <option value="1">OPtion</option>
    <option value="2">OPtion</option>
</select>
```

Вторая страница:

```
<select name="test">
    <option <?php if($_POST['test'] == '1') { echo 'selected'; } ?> value="1">OPtion</option>
    <option <?php if($_POST['test'] == '2') { echo 'selected'; } ?> value="2">OPtion</option>
</select>
```

Comment: если для отправки используется ```get```, а не ```post```, то имя переменной массива следует заменить на ```$_GET```

Comment: или же $_REQUEST

Comment: ```$_REQUEST``` удобнее, но в то же время с ним надо быть осторожным... не всегда он уместен